# write async function with EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am new in node and try to use async and event behavior advantages in node. I used to understand from node, everything that handle with Event object, it gonna be async execution.
Then i had try this, consider following code:

```
var events = require("events");

var event = new events.EventEmitter();


event.on("work", function () {

    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log("I do my work " + i);
    }

    event.emit("done");
});

var async = function (cb) {

    event.on("done", cb);
    event.emit("work");
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log("Async " + i);
    }
}


async(function () {
    console.log("I am done callback!");
});
```

This is async execution? In my opinion no! Why, because i had read this sentence many:

> An event is fired, so go and do something and then when you have finished it, come
>   back and tell me, but in meanwhile i will do something else.

Like a fast food restaurant scenario. But the code above, when the event work gonna fired, following sequence will happen:

1. go into the callback
2. let through the loop
3. output I do my work n
4. fired the done event
5. output I am done callback!
6. output Async n

why I am done callback! gonna output before Async n? Why is here not like fast food restaurant scenario, like

> the work event is fired, go and do you stuff and come back when you
>   done, in meanwhile i will output Async n

This is i used to understand about event driven behavior and async in node. But now i am very confused. I know, javascript works on single thread. How can i write an async function with event emitter? But i think is not possible, because when i emit an event, it will immediately execute the handler.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I used to understand from node, everything that handle with Event
>   object, it gonna be async execution.

This is incorrect. Events are synchronous. When you add a listener, you're just saving the callback in an object:

```
this._events[type].push(listener);
```

When you emit an event, you're just iterating an array and calling each listener:

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
      listeners[i].apply(this, args);
```

Source code: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js

> This is async execution? In my opinion no!

You are correct. It's async if you call any I/O function or use `setImmediate`, `nextTick` or a timer—otherwise, it's synchronous. A synchronous code being written asynchrously doesn't convert it to an asynchrous code.

> why I am done callback! gonna output before Async n?

Because when you receive the "done" callback you call to "cb":

```
event.on("done", cb);
```

When `cb` returns, the "Async n" loop is executed.

> How can i write an async function with event emitter?

Using `setImmediate` or `process.nextTick`.

If you want to postpone the "I do my work" loop execution, you can wrap the line `events.emit ("work")` with `nextTick`.

```
var events = require("events");

var event = new events.EventEmitter();


event.on("work", function () {

    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log("I do my work " + i);
    }

    event.emit("done");
});

var async = function (cb) {

    event.on("done", cb);
    process.nextTick (function () {         //<-----
        event.emit("work");
    });                                     //<-----
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        console.log("Async " + i);
    }
}


async(function () {
    console.log("I am done callback!");
});
```

This will print:

```
Async 0
Async 1
Async 2
Async 3
Async 4
Async 5
Async 6
Async 7
Async 8
Async 9
Async 10
I do my work 0
I do my work 1
I do my work 2
I do my work 3
I do my work 4
I do my work 5
I do my work 6
I do my work 7
I do my work 8
I do my work 9
I do my work 10
I am done callback!
```

Comment: The event loop will be execute again, after the codes in the stack has been completed. For example, i have 3 lines of code. The first is process.nextTick(dosomething) and other just console.log("something");.
Then the event loop will be execute right? And at the beginning of this loop, the callback that registered in process.nextTick() will be execute. Right?

Comment: look at the following code, when i call /test1 and in other browser /test2, it need a long time to get response on /test2, for me it is like /test1 block /test2
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/test1', function(req, res){
 
   for(var i = 0; i<= 100000000000; i++){
    
 }
  res.send('The loop is finished');
});

app.get('/test2', function(req, res){
  res.send('No loop');
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Express started on port 3000');

Comment: /test1 is "blocking" the event loop. That's why node is not for cpu intensive tasks. You could spawn a new process and do there these tasks. Read this article to fully understand concurrency in node: http://neilk.net/blog/2013/04/30/why-you-should-use-nodejs-for-CPU-bound-tasks/