# NodeJS 7: EventEmitter + await/async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

How we can end an `async` function from a callback passed to an event emitter **without promisifing the event emitter**?

Also without using *external modules*, just plain **NodeJS 7.x/8.x** (Which supports **Es6** syntax and `async/await`.

We want basically to mix an `async function ...` with an event emitter, so that it resolves when the event emitter signals `end`.

Also bear in mind that we won't start with the event emitter until done with some other async functions, using `await`.

If we had a "new Promise(...)" we would call resolve(); and the headache would be over, but in 'async' there's no 'resolve', plus we cannot use 'return' because we're inside a callback.

```
/*
 * Example of mixing Events + async/await.
 */

// Supose a random pomise'd function like:
function canIHazACheezBurger () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(Math.random() > 0.5);
    }, 500 + Math.random() * 500)
  });
}

/**
 * Then, we want to mix an event emitter with this logic,
 * what we want is that this function resolves the promise
 * when the event emitter signals 'end' (for example).
 * Also bear in mind that we won't start with the event emitter
 * until done with the above function.
 * If I had a "new Promise(...)" I would call resolve(); and the
 * headache would be over, but in 'async' there's no 'resolve',
 * plus I cannot use 'return' because I'm inside a callback.
 */
async function bakeMeSomeBurgers () {
  let canIHave = await canIHazACheezBurger();
  // Do something with the result, as an example.
  if (canIHave) {
    console.log('Hehe, you can have...');
  } else {
    console.log('NOPE');
  }
  // Here invoke our event emitter:
  let cook = new BurgerCooking('cheez');
  // Assume that is a normal event emitter, like for handling a download.
  cook.on('update', (percent) => {
    console.log(`The burger is ${percent}% done`);
  });
  // Here lies the problem:
  cook.on('end', () => {
    console.log('I\'ve finished the burger!');
    if (canIHave) {
      console.log('Here, take it :)');
    } else {
      console.log('Too bad you can\'t have it >:)');
    }
    // So, now... What?
    // resolve(); ? nope
    // return; ?
  });
}
```

### Disclaimer

I want to apologize if this question is already done somewhere. The research done shows questions related to mix async with sync logic, but I've found nothing about this.

A similar question in title is [this 'write async function with EventEmitter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740988/write-async-function-with-eventemitter) but it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: No, it's not possible using `async`/`await` without promisifying the thing you're trying to wait for.

Comment: Too bad, thanks! That's what I wanted to know. So I suppose that I will start to write a domain specific promisifier o return promises from event emitters...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Can we end an async function from a callback passed to an event emitter without promisifing the event emitter?

**No**. `async`/`await` syntax is just sugar for `then` calls and relies on promises.

```
async function bakeMeSomeBurgers () {
  let canIHave = await canIHazACheezBurger();
  if (canIHave)
    console.log('Hehe, you can have...');
  else
    console.log('NOPE');

  // Here we create and await our promise:
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Here invoke our event emitter:
    let cook = new BurgerCooking('cheez');
    // a normal event callback:
    cook.on('update', percent => {
      console.log(`The burger is ${percent}% done`);
    });
    cook.on('end', resolve); // call resolve when its done
    cook.on('error', reject); // don't forget this
  });

  console.log('I\'ve finished the burger!');
  if (canIHave)
    console.log('Here, take it :)');
  else
    console.log('Too bad, you can\'t have it >:)');
}
```

Comment: Wrapping the event emitter's end method is something that I didn't think about, nice!

Comment: @SigmaSoldier Well that's exactly what I understood as "promisifying the event emitter" :-)

Comment: I had in mind a method like `util.promisify`, but in Node 7.x is not available (So I cannot use it in Electron for now), but I didn't think in such a simple and elegant way ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class that extends `Node.js EventEmitter` to support async event listeners and provides a function to wait for an event to be processed completely before proceeding with the rest of your code:

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';

export const EventResolverSymbol = Symbol.for('EventResolver');

export class AsyncEventEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  private listenerMap = new WeakMap<
    (...args: any[]) => void,
    (...args: any[]) => void
  >();

  emitAsync(eventName: string | symbol, ...args: any[]): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
      resolve.prototype.key = EventResolverSymbol;
      super.emit(eventName, ...args, resolve);
    });
  }

  on(eventName: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this {
    const wrappedListener = async (...args: any[]) => {
      // check if event called from `awaitForEventDone` function
      if (args?.length) {
        const resolver = args[args.length - 1];
        if (
          typeof resolver === 'function' &&
          resolver.prototype.key === EventResolverSymbol
        ) {
          try {
            await listener(...args);
          } catch (e) {}
          return await resolver();
        }
      }
      return await listener(...args);
    };
    this.listenerMap.set(listener, wrappedListener);
    return super.on(eventName, wrappedListener);
  }

  once(eventName: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): this {
    const wrappedListener = async (...args: any[]) => {
      if (args?.length) {
        const resolver = args[args.length - 1];
        if (
          typeof resolver === 'function' &&
          resolver.prototype.key === EventResolverSymbol
        ) {
          try {
            await listener(...args);
          } catch (e) {}
          // remove listeners after the event is done
          this.removeListener(eventName, listener);
          this.removeListener(eventName, wrappedListener);
          return await resolver();
        }
      }
      // remove listeners after the event is done
      this.removeListener(eventName, listener);
      this.removeListener(eventName, wrappedListener);
      return await listener(...args);
    };
    this.listenerMap.set(listener, wrappedListener);
    return super.once(eventName, wrappedListener);
  }

  removeListener(
    eventName: string | symbol,
    listener: (...args: any[]) => void,
  ): this {
    const wrappedListener = this.listenerMap.get(listener);
    if (wrappedListener) {
      this.listenerMap.delete(listener);
      return super.removeListener(eventName, wrappedListener);
    }

    return this;
  }

  off = this.removeListener;
}
```

### Example

```
 // Create a new async event emitter
 const emitter = new AsyncEventEmitter();
 
 // Define an async event listener
 const listener = async (message: string) => {
   console.log('event start with param: ', message);
   await sleep(5000);
 };
 
 // Listen for 'greet' event
 emitter.on('TestEvent', listener);
 
 // Emit the 'greet' event and wait for it to be done
 emitter.emitAsync('TestEvent', 'Hello World!');
    // will be call after 5000ms delay
   .then(() => console.log('event done'));
```

Comment: `resolve.prototype.key` does not work