# Using async in event emitter

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, eventemitter

I am being challenged trying to make an async call inside an event.

Here's the code from [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/) - I've added the line where I need to make an async call:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    SES: new aws.SES({
        apiVersion: '2010-12-01'
    }),
    sendingRate: 1 // max 1 messages/second
});

// Push next messages to Nodemailer
transporter.on('idle', () => {
    while (transporter.isIdle()) {

        // I need to make an async db call to get the next email in queue
        const mail = await getNextFromQueue()

        transporter.sendMail(mail);
    }
});
```

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967019/nodejs-7-eventemitter-await-async) which suggest switching things around which makes sense however I have been unable to apply it correctly to this.

*Update* - The answer was to mock sendMail using Sinon.

Comment: Can't you just mark the callback to `idle` as `async` and then use `await` inside of it as usual?

Comment: That didn't seem to work as that was my first try. Events dont run async. Perhaps i made a coding error if you really think that should work

Comment: I've added an answer - **but** - on second thought, if you can't get it to work it might be because `transporter.on` is not the same as `EventEmitter.on`. Instead it could assume internally that the callback function provided is not a `Promise`, which is more-or-less what the `async` keyword does. I'm inclined to believe that that's not the case but it is a possibility. If that's the case you might want to wrap `async` in an IIFE

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just mark your callback as `async` and use `await` inside of it.

The fact that it's an `event` handler callback makes no difference since at the end it's just a plain-old `Function`.

#### Node snippet

```
'use strict'

const EventEmitter = require('events')
const myEmitter = new EventEmitter()

const getDogs = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(['Woof', 'Woof', 'Woof'])
    }, 500)
  })
}

myEmitter.on('event', async () => {
  const dogs = await getDogs()
  console.log(dogs)
})

myEmitter.emit('event')
```

#### Alternative scenario

If you still can't get it to work it might be because `transporter.on` is not the same as `EventEmitter.on` - meaning it's a custom function provided by `transporter`.

It could assume internally that the callback function provided is not a `Promise` - keep in mind that labelling a function as `async` forces the function to always implicitly return a `Promise`.

If that's the case you might want to wrap the `async` function in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

```
// ..rest of code from above

myEmitter.on('event', () => {
  // wrap into an IIFE to make sure that the callback 
  // itself is not transformed into a Promise
  (async function() {
    const dogs = await getDogs()
    console.log(dogs)
  })()
})

myEmitter.emit('event')
```

Comment: It is an EventEmitter  - https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/lib/ses-transport/index.js#L50

Comment: Ahh... I think my test framework is the issue. Calling the sample from CLI works but not form Ava. I have my outer function async but since nothing returns a promise it just ends. Will have to explore this a bit more.

Comment: Yup. My test was the issue. It's of course not waiting so adding a timeout should handle the issue. I had misdiagnosed my issue.

Comment: To be honest I'm thinking that you're misusing your test framework - you should be able to do something similar to Mocha's `done` in event handlers

Comment: Using `done` would work (t.end in ava) if I just test the event firing. But I need to assure the async function inside did its job so I need a little time to check that. Doesn't that make sense?

Comment: You are exposing yourself to a race hazard by waiting an arbitrary amount of time - then again you are right, it really is a tricky scenario

Comment: Use a [mocking library](http://sinonjs.org/) to *mock* the call to `sendMail`. This way you can be notified when `transporter.sendMail` is called so you can end your test reliably.

Comment: I don't think that will work. My real issue is preventing the function from existing early. Essentially this is the equivalent of running an async function inside a sync one and not waiting for a callback. What might work is mocking the event emitter inside using an async though that would require changing my code to return an async fn from the `on` event as you suggested - it just would not do anything in real time.

Comment: It's worth a shot though. Let me see if Sinon can help.

Comment: Should your test end when `transporter.sendMail` is called successfully, either sync or async?

Comment: I got it to work - thank you for your suggestion. I ended up mocking `sendMail` to check it was fetching multiple mail and another test with mocking some non shown function that logs the result of the mail and mocking the SES call using nock.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to rename `myEmitter` to `whoLetTheDogs` with a listener on `out`?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar scenario and if I were you I would have done the following.

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
SES: new aws.SES({
    apiVersion: '2010-12-01'
}),
sendingRate: 1 // max 1 messages/second
});

const sendMail = async () => {
    while (transporter.isIdle()) {
        // I need to make an async db call to get the next email in queue
        const mail = await getNextFromQueue()

        transporter.sendMail(mail);
    }
}

// Push next messages to Nodemailer
transporter.on('idle', sendMail);
```

Comment: This is no different from inlining the `sendMail` function as an async function, as per Nik's answer