# NodeJS 8.x: EventEmitter + async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, eventemitter

how I can use async functions with event emitter, in other information sources saying: **do not use async functions with event emitter.**

I want basically to mix an async function with an event emitter, so that it resolves and event emitter show the messages.

The code is as follows:

```
server.on('published', async (packet, client) => { // event emitter with async function
  debug(`Received: ${packet.topic}`)

  switch (packet.topic) {
    case 'agent/connected':
    case 'agent/disconnected':
      debug(`Payload: ${packet.payload}`)
      break
    case 'agent/message':
      debug(`Payload: ${packet.payload}`)

      const payload = parsePayload(packet.payload)

      if (payload) {
        payload.agent.connected = true

        let agent
        try {
          agent = await Agent.createOrUpdate(payload.agent)
        } catch (e) {
          return handleError(e)
        }
        debug(`Agent ${agent.uuid} saved`)

        // Notify Agent is Connected
        if (!clients.get(client.id)) {
          clients.set(client.id, agent)
          server.publish({
            topic: 'agent/connected',
            payload: JSON.stringify({
              agent: {
                uuid: agent.uuid,
                name: agent.name,
                hostname: agent.hostname,
                pid: agent.pid,
                connected: agent.connected
              }
            })
          })
        }

        // Store Metrics
        for (let metric of payload.metrics) {
          let m

          try {
            m = await Metric.create(agent.uuid, metric)
          } catch (e) {
            return handleError(e)
          }

          debug(`Metric ${m.id} saved on agent ${agent.uuid}`)
        }
      }
      break
  }
})
```

I want to apologize if this question is already done somewhere. I new in nodejs and I've found nothing about similar.

A similar question in title [NodeJS 7: EventEmitter + await/async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967019/nodejs-7-eventemitter-await-async)  but it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: does the code work? if not, describe the problem you are having, as "it doesn't work" is not a vlaid problem description

Comment: "*in other information sources saying*" - where does it say that, can you please link those? Also, why don't you believe them?

Comment: Yes, you can use `async` functions as callbacks anywhere. However, the event emitter will not gain anything from this, it'll just throw the returned promises away.

Comment: @JaromandaX No, my code doesn't not work, basically mi question that bears with this thread https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/issues/711 and not understand the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The main problem of using async functions in event emmiter - is that you cannot handle resulting promise rejection. So you can do something like this:

```
const asyncEventHandler = async function(...args) { /* do anything here */ };
const eventHandlerWrapper = function(...args) {
  const promise = asyncEventHandler(...args);
  promise.catch(function(error) {
    // handle error here
  });
};

emitter.on("some-event", eventHandlerWrapper);
```

On the other hand - with sync function, you know, that listeners will call in sequence (next one starts when previous ends). With async listeners next listener will start right after first `await` in current listener. And there is nothing you can do with this.

Comment: No, that's not a problem with `async` functions specifically. *All* emitter callbacks must not throw, you just have to handle all errors. Whether you do that with a wrapper function or with `try`/`catch` inside the function itself doesn't make a difference.