# Not able to access the variable outside of a request

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I'm a new to coding and currently struggling with promises and await/async. I'm trying to access the data coming from the `currPrice` variable outside of the function scope. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
        var price
        const getPrice = async () => {
           
            //Get the curent market price
            var marketSymobl = checkOrders[i].symbol.split(" - ")[0].toUpperCase()
            console.log(checkOrders[i].symbol)
           finnhubClient.quote(marketSymobl, (error, data, response) => {  
            const currPrice = data.c
             console.log(currPrice);
             return currPrice             
                });
        
            }
   
       //const x = getPrice().then(price => (console.log(x)))
          
         price = await getPrice()
         console.log(price);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS 7: EventEmitter + await/async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967019/nodejs-7-eventemitter-await-async)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when you do `return currPrice` you are returning from the callback in the `quote` function, thus not getting the value in the scope of the `getPrice` function. Because this is a callback, once it is executed the `getPrice` function already left the event stack with `undefined` as the return value. Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) to learn about the event loop.

A way you could fix this would be to do something like:

```
const getPrice = async () => {
  //Get the curent market price
  const marketSymobl = checkOrders[i].symbol.split(" - ")[0].toUpperCase()     
  
  // We are wrapping this function in a promise so that we can await it
  const quotePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => finnhubClient.quote(marketSymobl, (error, data, response) => {
    if (error) {
       // Rejecting with error so you have the freedom to handle it however you want
       reject(error)
    } else {
       resolve(data.c)
    }
  });
  
  const currPrice = await quotePromise();

  return currPrice
}
```

This way you are returning from the `getPrice` function.

Note: I changed your `var` variables to `let`. Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var) for an explanation why

Edit 1: I changed your `marketSymobl` variable to be `const`, since you don't mutate it afterwards

Edit 2: Wrapped the quote function in a promise so it can be awaited

Edit 3: Edited initial statement and added reference to event loop video.

Comment: Hi Pedro. Thank you so much for you input. Unfortunately, anything that's outside of the quote function comes back undefined. I seem to be running out ideas.

Comment: What's the return type of the quote function? It might be a promise that you need to await for

Comment: @PedroFilipe the above method will return null as the `cb` will be executed  later in the execution in the event loop.  It will always retun `null`. You need to make a change in the above function using await.

Comment: I hadn't notice that the getPrice function was already an async function X)

Comment: I've managed to get it working with Pedro's code. Thank you very much for your input @PedroFilipe. NOTE: I've had to change const currPrice = await quotePromise() to const currPrice = await quotePromise as I was getting a TypeError: quotePromise() is not a function

Comment: Although, I have just one question. If finnhubClient.quote function is not promised based then what is it?

Comment: It returns callback and in callback it returns the resukt or error.

Answer (score 1):

`Async/await` is just a syntactic sugar over promises. Promise can be returned as resolved or rejected and you use `then/catch` block to get the result/error based on the promise status returned. I am attaching a [link](https://dev.to/watysom/i-promise-your-deep-understanding-of-promise-b15) to go through and understand how they work and when they are needed.

Now, let's understand the code you wrote:

```
        var price;

        // async method automatically returns promise
        const getPrice = async () => {
           
            //Get the curent market price
            var marketSymobl = checkOrders[i].symbol.split(" - ")[0].toUpperCase()
            console.log(checkOrders[i].symbol);

           // callback which is called when the async
           // task is completed or failed with error, so using await we can
           // make it await for this async task to complete first 
           // and then move to subsequent lines
           // try to put await code under try/catch

           try {
           const currPrice = await finnhubClient.quote(marketSymobl) // if this return the promise
            return currPrice.c
            } catch(e) {
              console.log(e);
            }
         }
        // here x will never get the value returned from getPrice. 
        // to get the values form getPrice, you can use then operator
        // on x like this
        //const x = getPrice();
        // x.then(price => (console.log(x))).catch((e) => console.log(e));

      
       //const x = getPrice().then(price => (console.log(x)))
          
         price = await getPrice(); // this will return the response or error based on promise value
         console.log(price);
```

Note: `finnhubClient.quote` if this method returns the promise the above code will work fine else it won't work. Also, I suggest you to check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) link for async/await.

When `finnhubClient.quote` is not promise based, you can return promise.

```
const getPrice = () => {
           
     return new Promise((res, rej) => {
         //Get the curent market price
            var marketSymobl = checkOrders[i].symbol.split(" - ")[0].toUpperCase()
            console.log(checkOrders[i].symbol)
           finnhubClient.quote(marketSymobl, (error, data, response) => {       
            if (error) reject(error);
            const currPrice = data.c
             console.log(currPrice);
             resolve(currPrice)            
            });
        
     })
            
}
```

Comment: You can only await the quote function if it returns a promise, otherwise it won't do anything, you will need to wrap that function in a promise

Comment: Hi Apoorva, Thank you very much for your explanation. I've tried adding await to the quote function. However I'm getting this error:           
       Warning: superagent request was sent twice, because both .end() and .then() were called. Never call .end() if you use promises
Error: .end() was called twice. This is not supported in superagent

Comment: Check out my edited answer to see if it solves your problem

Comment: @PedroFilipe thats why I have added a note for that specific function. If SO can add the implementation of that function I can make it promise based.

Comment: @Calin89, you need to make `finnhubClient.quote` promise based or you can share the definition. I can help with that.

Comment: From the name of the function I inferred @Calin89 is using https://github.com/Finnhub-Stock-API/finnhub-js, so I went to check their API, which is not promise based

Comment: @PedroFilipe If it's not promised based then how do I solve this problem? I've tried your edited code and getting. const currPrice = await quotePromise();
                                        ^

TypeError: quotePromise is not a function

Comment: I apologies in advance for this newbie questions. I've tried for almost 10hrs to solve this and no luck so far.  I've only started coding a month ago.

Comment: Thats fine. Things happen. Let me update the answer and check that.

Comment: Just updated the answer, whenever you have a method which is not promise based you can convert that with this format and you are good to go.